# jQuery - how to make two separate animations

Tags: jquery, animation

I need help with some animation. Im trying to make div1, div2 and div3 slide to the right and div4, div5 and div6 slide to the left. At the moment I can't seem to seperate the two and all seem to slide in the same direction. I am new to jQuery and just learning, any help will be appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
<script> 

var animateMe = function(targetElement, speed){
$(targetElement).css({left:'-200px'});
$(targetElement).animate(
    {
    'left': $(document).width() 
    },
    {
    duration: speed,
    complete: function(){
        animateMe(this, speed);
        }
    }
 );
};

$(document).ready(function(){
animateMe($("#div1"), 15000);
animateMe($("#div2"), 13000);
animateMe($("#div3"), 14000);
});

var animateMe = function(targetElement, speed){

$(targetElement).css({right:'-200px'});
$(targetElement).animate(
    {
    'right': $(document).width() 
    },
    {
    duration: speed,
    complete: function(){
        animateMe(this, speed);
        }
    }
);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
animateMe($("#div4"), 16000);
animateMe($("#div5"), 14000);
animateMe($("#div6"), 13000);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a race condition, where you set the `animateMe` var to a function, then re-set it, then after both of those occur, `document.ready` is firing and animating all the `<div />` elements using the second `animateMe` function.

Just because the code reads top-down, that doesn't mean that's how it will execute. Your code almost certainly executes like this:

```
[CREATE FUNCTION]
[OVERWRITE FUNCTION]
[ANIMATE 1, 2, 3]
[ANIMATE 4, 5, 6]
```

I suggest that you allow a parameter to be passed to the `animateMe` function for the property to animate, so you can use one function to animate all the elements.